# Lagrange Multiplier Problem - min attained, max not attained - why?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Consider the prolem where we need to both minimize and maximize $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ subject to $x = y+1$. (So $g(x,y) = x-y=1.)$

Setting up the Lagrange Multiplier equation $\nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y)$, we obtain
$$ \langle 2x,2y \rangle = \lambda \langle 1, -1\rangle $$

which implies that $2x=\lambda$ and $2y=-\lambda$

Now, if $x = 0$, then $\lambda = 0$, which would imply that $y=0$, but this does not satisfy $g(x,y) = 1$. In fact, solving $2x=\lambda$ and $2y=-\lambda$ for $x = \lambda/2$ and $2y=-\lambda$ for $y = -\lambda/2$ and substituting into $g(x,y) = x-y = 1$ gives us that $$ g(x,y)=x-y = 1 \\ \implies \frac{\lambda}{2} - \left(-\frac{\lambda}{2}\right) = 1 \\ \implies \lambda = 1 \\ \implies x = \frac{1}{2}\, \text{and}\, y = -\frac{1}{2} $$

So, our only critical point is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{-1}{2} \right)$, which in the context of the problem cannot be both the max and the min.

**My Question is: I was told that in this problem, $f$ attains its max, but its min is not attained, and I was told that in order to explain this, I need to explain the "boundary behaviour" of $f$ - i.e., what happens as we go to $\infty$ along the line $x = y+1$. However, I don't understand what is meant by that - could somebody please explain it to me?**

I figured drawing a picture would be helpful, so I'm including it here: [image]
Essentially, what I did was draw a bunch of level curves of $f$ for various constants $k$, and draw the line $g$ on the same graph, but I don't understand what is happening as we go to $\infty$ along $g$. I have to teach this to a bunch of undergrads in a few hours, and I'd like to understand what I'm trying to teach them, so if you could kindly explain it to me, I would appreciate it more than you know! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $M\in\mathbb R$, there exists a point $(x,y)$ on the line $y=x+1$ such that $f(x,y)>M$. In particular, one such point would be $x=\max\{1,M\}, y=\max\{1,M\}+1$.

Therefore, the function is not bounded on the line (and has no maximum).

---

Another way of saying the same thing would be to say this:

If we parametrize the line as $(t,1+t)$, with $t\in\mathbb R$, then $$\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t,1+t) = \infty$$

Comment: let me get this straight: for every $M \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists (x, x+1)$ such that $f(x, x+1) = (x)^{2} + (x+1)^{2} > M$?

Comment: @ALannister Exactly. For example, for $M>1$, you have $f(M,M+1)>M$.

Comment: thanks a lot! I think you might have just pulled my bum out of the fire.

Comment: @ALannister To be honest, you did most of the work yourself with finding the minimum. Showing there is no maximum is actually the easier part, once you get the idea.

Comment: one thing though is how would I know that the point that I found is necessarily a minimum and not a maximum? Would I need to do the second derivative test just to make sure?

Comment: @ALannister Well, you know that the function *has* a minimum (because it is bounded from below by $0$, and it's value is large outside some bounded - compact - set). You also know that the discovered point is either a minimum or a maximum, therefore it has to be the minimum. So you don't need second derivatives for that.

Comment: aaah, brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: @ALannister Nothing brilliant about it, in fact, it's quite a standard sequence of deductions. Once you do 100 of them, the next one is super easy. You'll get there :)